# Qt online installer: only 64-bit for Linux

Tags: linux, qt

From [here](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) it seems since Qt 5.6 the online installer for Linux are available only for 64-bit hosts.
In fact, the online installer for x86 will show Qt versions up to 5.5 only.

Is there a reason for that?

I mean, to use the newer versions, should I use a 64-bit development machine?
I'm interested in QtCreator only, because I'm going to cross-compile the Qt framework for ARM.

As far as I understand the lastest version of QtCreator requires a 64-bit machine: https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator

Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but a question: Especially if you are cross-compiling anyway, why would you want to use anything but 64 bit development OS?

Comment: I had a lot of problem in the past with host libraries. Fixed simply switching to 32-bit. Perhaps now it would be flawless (after reconfiguring everything...)

Comment: Strictly speaking you don't need Qt Creator for cross-compiling Qt framework at all. I did that not just once and cannot remember all details for all platforms and now build Qt as part of "platform" build with BitBake scenario. That builds entire Linux image with our software. Then after it is build we able to produce a separate target SDK for integrating with whatever: command line or maybe Qt Creator.

Comment: I don't need QtCreator for cross-compiling Qt framework indeed! But I'd like to use it as code editor and debugger...

Comment: Then there is no problem at all. It is GDB and not Qt Creator that does the debug. If you experienced problems then that was about actual debugger and not the UI that interfaces with GDB. I use it every day. Cannot say why debug is prevented because of Qt Creator. Take newest Qt Creator and use it. Some setup maybe needed.

Comment: Please, read again question and comments. I didn't say I have/had problem with *debugging*. I'm just asking if it is correct that the latest QtCreator versions require a 64-bit machine.